# How to do password encryption for onvif in python?

Tags: php, python, onvif, python-onvif

For use `onvif` password must be encrypted in a certain kind. The method described in [ONVIF Appicaltion Programmer's Guide](http://www.onvif.org/Portals/0/documents/WhitePapers/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmer%27s_Guide.pdf) on page 35. I also found how to do this in PHP, it looks like this:

```php
$nonce      = pack('H*', mt_rand());
$passdigest = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($nonce . pack('a*', timestamp) . pack('a*', password))));
```

The main problem is that I don't know how all that byte operations works, so I need some help to transfer this PHP code in to the python...

Answer (score 1):

from: https://github.com/Pegax/pyOnvif

```
n64 = ''.join(SystemRandom().choice(string.letters + string.digits+string.punctuation) for _ in range(22))
nonce = base64.b64encode(n64)
#n64 = base64.b64decode(nonce)
pdigest= base64.b64encode(sha1(n64+created+self.password).digest())
```